# Show $E=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty}\{x: f_n(x)>k\}$ if $\{f_n\}$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Show $E=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty}\{x: f_n(x)>k\}$ if $\{f_n\}$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and $E=\{x: \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=+\infty\}$

My Approach:

$(\Rightarrow)$ Let $x\in E$, then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=+\infty$

$\implies\text{Given }k>1$, $f_n(x)>k\text{ for all but fintely many n}$

$\implies\exists N\in\mathbb{N}^+$, such that $f_{N-1}(x)\leq k$

$\implies x\in\{x: f_n(x)>k\text{ , }\forall n\geq N\}=\bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty}\{x: f_n(x)>k\}\subset\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty}\{x: f_n(x)>k\}$

As k arbitrary, $x\in\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty}\{x: f_n(x)>k\}$ $\forall k>0$,

hence $x\in\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty}\{x: f_n(x)>k\}$

Hence $E\subset\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty}\{x: f_n(x)>k\}$

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $x\in\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty}\{x: f_n(x)>k\}$, then
$x\in\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty}\{x: f_n(x)>k\text{ as } k\rightarrow\infty\}$

$\implies x\in\bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty}\{x: f_n(x)>k\text{ as } k\rightarrow\infty\}$ for some $N>1$

$\implies x\in\{x: f_n(x)>k\text{ as } k\rightarrow\infty\text{ , }\forall n>N\}$ for some $N>1$

$\implies x\in\{x: \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)>\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}k=+\infty\}=E$
        $\implies\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty}\{x: f_n(x)>k\}\subset E$
Hence $E=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty}\{x: f_n(x)>k\}$

Sort of tedious, but is my approach correct? Is there simpler way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you wnat to show? You just defined a set using functions defined in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: you have a typo in the last line after 'Hence'.. and you need to define $E$ in your post which i pressume is the set of $x$ sch that $f_n(x) \to +\infty$...your proof is almost correct..the important part is that you have the right ideas for this problem..and the idea is to interpret the quantifiers as union and intersection and of course to understand why you must do so..;)

Comment: @MariosGretsas Thx, typo corrected. You say "almost" which mean there arestill some minor mistakes, I wonder what that will be?

Comment: It is the part where you must define $E$ and in the fourth line instead of 'infinitely many $n$..the correct is to say 'for all but finitely many $n$..which is in the definition of the finite/infinite limit of a sequence..

Comment: @MariosGretsas I see, thank you so much.

Comment: @Unavailable also for the $( \Leftarrow)$ part you can just notice directly the the elements that belong in the(fancy) set they satisfy the definition of the limit of a sequence to infinity..if you write down the definition then you'll see that  it is obvious,,.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty}\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f_n(x)>k\} = \liminf_{n\to\infty}\,\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f_n(x)>k\} = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f_n(x) > k \text{ for all except finitely many } n\in\mathbb{N}\}
$$

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(t) =+\infty \iff \forall k \in\mathbb{N}$ we have $t \in \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f_n(x) > k \text{ for all except finitely many } n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, we conclude:

\begin{align} E&=\{x\in\mathbb{R}: \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=+\infty\} \\
&= \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f_n(x) > k \text{ for all except finitely many } n\in\mathbb{N}\} \\
&= \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \liminf_{n\to\infty}\,\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f_n(x)>k\} \\
&= \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty}\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f_n(x)>k\}
\end{align}